# variable from js to html to save value/lose value of max after dying and restarting game scene/phaser-js

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

So the question I have to make is the following; My project Structure is:

- index.html
- StartScene.js
- GameScene.js
- game.js
- 2 pictures(png) for media files

So I'm making some games with phaser. In my game scene, I have a variable named `max` which is the max of an array that stores all the scores as the game progresses and the player gets better scores, etc.

So it's inside the function `create()` of my `GameScene` class. The problem is every time the player dies I do `this.scene.restart()`, so all the variables lose their values and my max is not the max from the previous run but 0.

Is there a way to fix this?
(I thought of storing the value to the index.html file then writing a script making an array with all the values and then finding max of that array and printing it out.)

THNX IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing is probably rather than making max a member of the scene you could just have it be global on window. So something like

```
if(window.max === undefined) {
  window.max = 0
} else if(score > window.max) {
  window.max = score;
}
```

In javascript window is a global object.

Comment: Is it possible to NOT reset  the score to 0 during your this.scene.restart? If so, then you  then calculate the score by using MollyJ's method. Then, persist this max score to the starting scene by calling this.scene.start("startScene", { maxValue: maxScore })  to proceed to the starting scene with the data. Then, you can access the variable from `data.maxaValue` in init(data) in the StartScene

Answer (score 0):

You could use registry's data manager to exchange data between scenes and set your max score just before you restart the Game's one.

Initialize in your StartScene's create your max value:

```
this.registry.set('max', 0);
```

Set your max score just before restarting:

```
this.registry.set('max', this.score);
this.scene.restart()
```

Check the Registry where needed for changes and hit the callback

```
this.registry.events.on('changedata', this.doStuff, this);
```

[Registry data exchange example on docs.](http://Registry%20Data%20Exchange)

Here's also Rex's [plugin for restorable data](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/restorabledata/) you can take a look at (among many other good things).